# Vagrant and installing packages in shared folder

Tags: linux, networking, npm, vagrant

I'm having trouble installing npm packages in vagrant.

I'm SSH inside vagrant and I'm trying to run `sudo npm install gulp` it doesnt work in the folder that vagrant shares between host and virtual machine.

But it works perfectly fine inside a seperate directory purely inside the VM.

This is part of the error I'm given:

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/vagrant/public/laravelproject/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-util/test/PluginError.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-60-generic-pae
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "gulp" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/public/laravelproject
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.6
npm ERR! path /vagrant/public/laravelproject/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-util/test/PluginError.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/public/laravelproject/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-util/test/PluginError.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
```

Anyone know how to give full access for the vm to access the directory on the host im trying to share with the VM, this is my vagrant config:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |c|
  c.vm.box = "precise32"
  c.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"
  c.vm.network :private_network, ip:"192.168.33.10"
  c.vm.synced_folder "./public", "/var/www/", owner:"root", group:"root"
end
```

Comment: Are you installing on host or guest machine? Are you using linux on both? What provider do you use with vagrant? I don't know the source of this error, but I might try to debug it a bit.

Comment: Host windows, VM linux ubuntu precise 32, trying to install from the vm into folders on host that are shared with VM. he problem is down to folder permissions I can only assume.

Answer (score 4):

Ok after ages of digging, I've found a solution which doesnt solve the problem fully but acts as a way to do what I want.

Here is where I found the answer [Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269727/npm-errors-when-installing-packages-on-windows-share)

But basically run `npm install --no-bin-links [packagename]`